# Entity Framework formats DateTime SQL parameter without milliseconds for optimistic concurrency

Tags: entity-framework, datetime, optimistic-concurrency

I'm trying to use a DateTime LastModifiedDate column with optimistic concurrency in Entity Framework (will likely upgrade it to DateTime2.) I've set the Concurrency Mode to Fixed. But when I retrieve an entity, change a column and try to save, get a concurrency exception.

The stored LastModifiedDate is `2017-01-04 21:16:55.283` but look at the SQL Entity Framework is generating for the update:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Facilities] 
SET [Password] = @0 
WHERE (([pk_FacilityID] = @1) AND ([LastModifiedDate] = @2)) 

-- @0: 'bz0dkK+smlat9psrIrbyXkxjpcXcDK1DeUiha7jCRkU=' (Type = String, Size = 255) 

-- @1: '6801bdcf-266d-46bd-b15e-dac21116208d' (Type = Guid) 

-- @2: '1/4/2017 9:16:55 PM' (Type = DateTime2)
```

Notice it's passing a formatted DateTime string for `@2` which does not include milliseconds. Well of course it doesn't match if it's not passing in the same value it retrieved! I've verified that at runtime, the .NET DateTime does include the 0.283 seconds. Please tell me there's a way to pass in the full value. Why does it behave this way and how can I change it to include milliseconds?

Comment: Why don't you use rowid as concurrency token?

Comment: We've found it valuable to have a human-readable time stamp of the created and last modified times. Since we're going to already have it, it seemed to make sense to use it for the purpose of concurrency as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-- @2: '1/4/2017 9:16:55 PM' (Type = DateTime2)
```

That's not the actual parameter value sent.  That's just the logging, and it leaves off the fractional seconds.  There is a problem, but that's not it.

If you profile you should see something like this, that shows the details of the parameter type and value.

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Facilities]
SET [Name] = @0
WHERE (([FacilityId] = @1) AND ([LastModified] = @2))
',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 int,@2 datetime2(7)',@0=N'newName',@1=1,@2='2017-08-31 15:45:55.3030000'
```

What's happening is the datetime2(7) value is not round-trip converting to and back from datetime.  And the easiest fix is just to use datetime2(7) for your table column.  If you want to use the column for optimistic concurrency control, you need the extra precision anyway.

So something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Ef6Test
{
    public class Facility
    {
        public int FacilityId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ConcurrencyCheck(),Column(TypeName ="datetime2")]
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    }

    class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());


            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                var f = db.Facilities.Add(new Facility() { LastModified = DateTime.Now, Name = "Faclity1" });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                var f = db.Facilities.First();
                f.Name = "newName";
                db.SaveChanges();
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, good to know the logging is inaccurate. But why does SQL unreliably compare DateTime with DateTime2? E.G. it considers '2017-09-01 22:02:53.950' and '2017-09-01 22:02:53.9500000' to be equal, but '2017-09-01 21:58:19.047' and '2017-09-01 21:58:19.0470000' unequal. I assumed it would cast one and the only difference is trailing zeros so why are they unequal _sometimes_?

Comment: The resolution of datetime is 3.33ms, leading to the same kinds of rounding issues you get converting decimal numbers to floating point.

Comment: But where exactly does that come into play? When I read `21:58:19.047` from the db (already rounded), .NET pads the right with 0s (no rounding), passes it back to SQL as a datetime2 which keeps those 0s as `21:58:19.0470000` (no rounding), and then it needs to compare. If I were going to compare, I would either convert my datetime to a datetime2 which would result in `21:58:19.0470000` or convert my datetime2 to a datetime which would be `21:58:19.047` without requiring rounding, right? I don't understand how `21:58:19.0470000 <> 21:58:19.047` unless the latter has hidden digits.

Comment: At database compatibility level of 130 or greater, `select cast( cast( '2017-09-01 21:58:19.047' as datetime) as datetime2)` returns `2017-09-01 21:58:19.0466667`, not `2017-09-01 21:58:19.0470000`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I'm not a DBA but in all of the programming and math I've had exposure to, adding precision to an already rounded number shouldn't change the value. If I have an integer 1 and convert it to a decimal it should be 1.00... not change to 0.999999. If datetime is rounded to the thousandths, why should becoming a datetime2 subtract .0003333 from it? There's clearly something I don't understand about one or both of the datatypes. Aside from all that, this seems to suggest that EF is incompatible with SQL datetime for any type of comparison?

Comment: The issue is that the numbers don't use the same base.  Just like floating point uses base-2 numbers, and decimals use base-10.  There simply is no datetime with the exact value of `2017-09-01 21:58:19.047`.  The nearest one is `2017-09-01 21:58:19.04662`.  One if the many reasons datetime2 should be used instead.