# How to change how Entity Framework generates SQL precision for Datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I have a table use id & DateTime column be the pk, but when I try to update data by Entity Framework like this:

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
{
    var item = (from item in context.BatchData
                where item.Id == 2
                select item ).FirstOrDefault();

    item.Title = "EF6TEST";

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get an error

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).

After I recorded the SQL, I know the reason now.

The SQL looks like this

```
'update [dbo].[BatchData]
set [BatchData_Title] = @0
where (([BatchData_Id] = @1) and ([BatchData_CreatedDateTime] = @2))

select [BatchData_Rowversion]
from [dbo].[BatchData]BatchUploadData
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [BatchData_Id] = @1 and [BatchData_CreatedDateTime]     = @2',
N'@0 varchar(30),@1 tinyint,@2 datetime2(7)',
@0='EF6TEST',@1=1,@2='2017-09-16 11:29:35.3720000'
```

So, the reason is `BatchData_CreatedDateTime` parameter in the SQL is `@2='2017-09-16 11:29:35.3720000'`, the precision is 7 and it should be `@2='2017-09-16 11:29:35.372'` .

And here is my question, How to fix it?

Comment: what datatype is your sql server using? DateTime or DateTime2?

Comment: My sql server using DateTime

Comment: The precision of DateTime in SQL Server is milliseconds (.fff). So .372 on the sql server side is correct

However, .NET DateTime would return a precision of 7, can you update your datatype to DateTime2?

Comment: I am afraid I can not change , it possible change the generator sql ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `IDbInterceptor` to change required data, here is an example of interceptor that changes type of parameters from `DateTime2` to `DateTime`, you can extend it to use it on a specific fields of your DB / DbCommand parameters.

```
public class DateInterceptor : IDbInterceptor, IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, 
        DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        var dateParameters = command.Parameters.OfType<DbParameter>()
            .Where(p => p.DbType == DbType.DateTime2);
        foreach (var parameter in dateParameters)
        {
            parameter.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
        }
    }
```

To use it add `DbInterception.Add(new DateInterceptor());` into the end of `OnModelCreating` of your dbContext class

Generated SQL will be changed from

> @2 datetime2(7)',@0=0,@1=1,@2='2017-09-24 14:41:33.7950485'

to

> @2 datetime',@0=0,@1=1,@2='2017-09-24 14:40:32.327'

Comment: Thank you very much , I tried DateInterceptor . 
And It worked

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is SQL 2016 or Azure SQL Database.

See this SO Question [Entity Framework formats DateTime SQL parameter without milliseconds for optimistic concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886733/entity-framework-formats-datetime-sql-parameter-without-milliseconds-for-optimis)

SQL 2016 has changed the way conversions work between datetime and datetime2.  To use for optimistic concurrency, you it's better to use datetime2(7).