# Entity Framework 6 always maps C# DateTime to SQL Server datetime2(7)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I am trying to map a code first EF context onto an existing database. I thought I had everything figured out until it started to fail deletes on a table that has a SQL Server `datetime` property as part of its primary key.

Upon closer inspection, it appears EF automatically maps C# `DateTime` properties to SQL Server `datetime2(7)`. So the generated delete statement (below) has too much precision to match the SQL Server `datetime` value.

```
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [dbo].[history_vehicle_battery_states]
WHERE (([timestamp] = @0) AND ([vehicle_id] = @1))',N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 int',@0='2017-12-07 08:31:21.6370000',@1=1
```

The value of the `DateTime` becomes "2017-12-07 08:31:21.6370000", whereas the value should be "2017-12-07 08:31:21.637" in order to match and properly delete the row.

It appears there are a few ways of handling this, but none of them as yielded a proper query. I have tried to use the fluent API to change the `DateTime` field to a `datetime` column type, to have a precision of 3, and both at once. In all three cases, it always uses the type `datetime2(7)` when I inspect the generated query.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886733/entity-framework-formats-datetime-sql-parameter-without-milliseconds-for-optimis) question too.  There are round-trip issues with the precision on `DateTime` that make it a poor choice for optimistic-concurrency. `DateTime2` can fix those.  You should consider updating the database if possible.  It suggests the problem isn't actually the precision, but the round-tripping of unrepresentable floating-point data.

Comment: Looks exactly like the first comment. I will give it a try then close it if it fixes it.

Comment: If neither of those options fix your issue, let us know, we can undo the close-duplicate votes, and keep looking for a solution.